# How do I align three columns to the center using CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to create an organization chart in HTML using CSS, and I'd like to make the spaces between `<li>` tags thiner.

- Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/8q9uxzb6/

I'd like to have the `margin-left` value on the line 89 in CSS at 3%, and have the three columns centered. However, I'm unable to center those columns when I change the `margin-left` value. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you want but have you tried to set `width: 33%;` and `float: left;` on the three elements and then `margin: 0 auto;` on the `body`?

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but you inspired me in finding the solution this `width: 33%;` of yours :D so thank you :)
Before, the sum of all `<li>`s (columns) was not exactly or around 100%, so I fixed it and it works now.
 - Here is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/8879ntch/

Comment: No worries, glad I could be of help!